# X+これを久しゅう meaning

Tags: meaning

In sentences like [here](http://yourei.jp/%E4%B9%85%E3%81%97%E3%82%85%E3%81%86%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F). What does it mean? Which of the dictionary meanings of 久しい do I apply here?

1. 幽谷先生が感歎**これを久しゅう**したのも無理ではない。
2. と、私は慨嘆**これを久しゅう**したことであった。

etc. (there are many more in the link)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case,

「[久]{ひさ}しい」＝「[長]{なが}い」 (temporal > spatial)

> 「Noun + これ + (を) + 久しゅうする」 means:
>
> "to do (noun) for a long time"

In real life, however, we mostly use this phrase with a limited number of nouns whose meanings  are related to "***exclamation***" such as 「[感嘆]{かんたん}」、「[慨嘆]{がいたん}」、「[三嘆]{さんたん}」, etc.  This is elegant speech, if you are wondering.

> = "to be amazed for a long time"

Regarding the 「しゅう」 part, you will hear 「よろしゅう」 to mean 「よろしく」 at least in Kansai if not in Kanto.  It is a remnant of Classical Japanese.

Answer (score 2):

感歎これを久しゅうした = 感歎(wonderment but 感嘆 is common) + これ(感歎のこと)を + 久しゅう(久しく is the 連用形 of adjective 久しい which means "for a long time" and 久しゅう is a dialect of 久しく) + した

It means I　felt admiration for a long time. However this sentence was used  at a  long time ago, it is rarely used now.